# Can C++20 `constinit` waive the need for nifty counter idiom?

Tags: c++, c++20, static-order-fiasco, constinit

C++20 introduced [`constinit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constinit) to avoid static initialization order fiasco.

Can `constinit` waive the need for the [nifty counter idiom](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter) (e.g. for initialization of `std::cout`)?

Comment: `constinit` doesn't stop static initialization order fiasco.  It's used to say that the variable must be constant or zero initialized. i.e `consinit int foo;` would be an error but `constinit int foo = 42;` would not be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can C++20 `constinit` waive the need for nifty counter idiom?

No.

Static initialisation order fiasco is only a problem with dynamic initialisation phase of static objects. Sure, if you don't do dynamic initialisation, then there is no problem, and `constinit` enforces that. But that doesn't solve anything when you need dynamic initialisation.

Comment: @ArdentCoder "new"? :P

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Lol I guess he has a huge fan base

Comment: Just for me bro, I am already aware of the fiasco problem and *when* it's happening, but can you just clarify what exactly you mean by **dynamic initialization**